# Amazon Web Services Kinesis , EMR and S3 at cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-kinesis

I have a use case where I need to send CSV data from multiple windows devices say usage hrs.
We have target usage hrs e.g. 80 hrs which has to be completed collectively. Now each PC will be sending its usage through kinesis stream and at cloud using EMR we will update the coverage.

e.g. PC1- 10hrs,PC2-20hrs, PC3 - 5hrs,PC4 -5hrs. So now cloud will send 80-(10+20+5+5)/4 = 10 to each PC . Now they have to cover only 10 hrs each.
The data will be streaming . But we have to save the data in S3 and also process and send back to EMR.

We are sending data using AWS sdk .net. I need to under stand the steps required once data is in kinesis streams what to do at cloud.

Comment: Hi @sidnandan, Can you please elaborate the design of your cloud more. And where you're getting confused. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Murtaza,We have not designed the full architecture yet . I am able to send data to kinesis stream. Now the data needs to be read from stream and stored in S3 as well as processed with EMR. Here's where I am confused what steps to perform on cloud to read stream and store data, also how to send updated data back to PC's

Comment: Ok, So correct me If I go wrong. You read from Kinesis apply some aggregation on EMR and then Store aggregated result or raw data? to S3.  And then you need to send this processed data back to your windows phone clients.

Comment: Yes correct just one clarification, when I read from kinesis I need to store data to input bucket of S3 before it goes to EMR and after aggregation on EMR store data on output bucket of S3 before sending to clients.

Comment: Ok some things to know. Your Input s3 file size? what framework your using to process your data on EMR? and from where and what data is going to deliver on your PC

Comment: The Input will come from stream, each record csv line will be of 1-2 kb. I will be using Hive to process the data. The processed data needs to be received by aws sdk .net program running on PCs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches as per your UseCase:

1) EMR based or Cluster Based

You can write up a spark-streaming program to consume your data from Kinesis, process over it and then dump the results to a NoSQL or Amazon S3. In the meantime you can also backup your Raw data using [KinesisS3Emitter](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors). After your result processed you can Send it to a SNS topic which is subscribed by your PC and your PC will get the processed output

2) Serverless

Instead of creating a Kinesis Stream, You can create a Firehose stream which will deliver your raw data to an S3 Location. Then you can configure a Lambda Function to process those S3 files and redirect the result to your another S3 Location or NoSQL. And same as above you can send it a SNS topic which will be subscribed by your PC.

These are the two approaches (Any corrections are welcome). You have to calculate the **computation speed, cost and resources to use** by your requirement and maintaining the **security** of your system. For ex : Instead of SNS topic you may required N number of SNS topics for N PCs etc.

Comment below for more and let people know what's best. Thanks

Comment: I will comment with the approach which worked for me . I ll try them out.